# xaml validation error rad line and error tooltip not disply using IDataErrorInfo?

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

In my project, for the validation i have used IDataErrorInfor and in xaml code i have mentioned NotifyfyOvalidationError= true for textbox.

All validations are performed correctly but only thing is that  in my view it not diplaying the error template as red line across TextBox and tooltip which i want to show as to observe that this TextBox Contains Error..

Same thind is works correctly for all other TextBoxs and anoother thing is that Validation for this TextBox is works form viewmodel whatever i have set in my code..

Xaml :

```
 <TextBox  Margin="0,7"  Text="{Binding Path=Address.AddressLines, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"  />
```

View Model :

## region IDataErrorInfo Members

```
string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return null; } }

string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
{
    get { return this.GetValidationError(propertyName); }
}

#endregion // IDataErrorInfo Members

#region Validation

/// <summary>
/// Returns true if this object has no validation errors.
/// </summary>
public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        foreach (string property in ValidatedProperties)
            if (GetValidationError(property) != null)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}

static readonly string[] ValidatedProperties = 
{ 
      "Address",
};
string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
{
    if (Array.IndexOf(ValidatedProperties, propertyName) < 0)
        return null;

    string error = null;

    switch (propertyName)
    {
      
        case "Address":
            error = this.ValidateAddressLine();
            break;
           
        default:
            Debug.Fail("Unexpected property being validated on School: " + propertyName);
            break;
    }

    return error;
}
string ValidateAddressLine()
{
    if (IsStringMissing(this.Address.AddressLines))
    {
        return "Enter Address.";
    }
    return null;
}

static bool IsStringMissing(string value)
{
    return
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ||
        value.Trim() == String.Empty;
}
#endregion // Validation
```

Any one find solution of my problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
      public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            var error = string.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Address.AddressLines":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address.AddressLines))
                        error = "Address.AddressLines Required";
                    break;


            }
            return error;
        }
    }
```

Use this code